# How can I restrict file types in SharePoint 2010, Any Tutorial

Tags: sharepoint-2010, file-type

I would need to restrict some file types in sharepoint 2010 like rft's etc.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly easy to do this in sharepoint 2010. Check the steps @ 
http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/06/restrict-certain-file-types-in.html

Comment: Pretty much the ame in WSS3 / MOSS 2007 : SharePoint Central Administration > Operations > Blocked file types